# Set Display Text Of ComboBox In Datagridview

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, combobox

How to Set Display Text Of ComboBox In Datagridview to for example :"Select combobox"

Set Text In Combo Box Is Simple but Set Text To Datagridviewcombobox is not like combobox

Any One Who Found Useful Link please help me,because i didnt find any link related to my problem

***EDITED:***

I mean,i want to show a text in combo box before user click on it

Comment: @Duane +1, is it just me, or has today been particularly bad for this kind of question?

Comment: Can you not add the same to your datasource ?

Comment: if this question is so easy and could be find with search,why anybody does not answer to it?i thought maybe you understood my problem mistakenly,so i edited my question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After All Of Down Votes I Founded My Solution !!!

First I added my items to combobox(i fetched data from sql server database with datareader and added them to combo box) then i added this properties to my datagridviewcolumn(dgv_col) :

```
dgv_col.DataPropertyName="name"
dgv_col.DisplayMember="name"
dgv_col.ValueMember="id"
```

name is a field in my table and id is the identity for each name

And Finally it Solved :)

Comment: Accept your own answer then so people know it was the solution.